# Rounding datetime based on time of day

Tags: python, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with timestamps shown below:

`6/30/2019  3:45:00 PM`

I would like to round the date based on time. Anything before 6AM will be counted as the day before.

```
6/30/2019  5:45:00 AM -> 6/29/2019
6/30/2019  6:30:00 AM -> 6/30/2019
```

What I have considered doing is splitting date and time into 2 different columns then using an if statement to shift the date (if time >= 06:00 etc). Just wondering there is a built in function in pandas to do this. Ive seen posts of people rounding up and down based on the closest hour but never a specific time threshold (6AM).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How is stored the timestamp ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please don't just post requirements, we're not here to be a code-writing service.  Instead, edit your question to show what you have tried and ask for help if you get stuck.  As is, your question warrants a downvote.  Please read [*I downvoted because no attempt was made*](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Thank you.

Comment: Im pulling the data from excel, i copied the cell and pasted it in the first line of code. The cell is formatted as 'Date' in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there could be a better way to do this.. But this is one way of doing it.

```
import pandas as pd    

def checkDates(d):
    if d.time().hour < 6:
        return d - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    else:
        return d

ls = ["12/31/2019  3:45:00 AM", "6/30/2019  9:45:00 PM", "6/30/2019  10:45:00 PM", "1/1/2019  4:45:00 AM"]
df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=["dates"])
df["dates"] = df["dates"].apply(lambda d: checkDates(pd.to_datetime(d)))
print (df)
                dates
0 2019-12-30 03:45:00
1 2019-06-30 21:45:00
2 2019-06-30 22:45:00
3 2018-12-31 04:45:00
```

Also note i am not taking into consideration of the time. when giving back the result.. 
if you just want the date at the end of it you can just get that out of the datetime object doing something like this

> print ((pd.to_datetime("12/31/2019  3:45:00 AM")).date()) >>> 2019-12-31

if understand python well and dont want anyone else(in the future) to understand what your are doing 
one liner to the above is.

```
df["dates"] = df["dates"].apply(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d) - pd.Timedelta(days=1) if pd.to_datetime(d).time().hour < 6 else pd.to_datetime(d))
```

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions worked, ended up going with the one line code.