# How to solve a system of equations and constraints for portfolio optimization?

Tags: python, solver, z3py

I have a `DataFrame` as follows  :

```
Name  Volatility    Return
a      0.0243        0.212
b      0.0321        0.431
c      0.0323        0.443
d      0.0391        0.2123
e      0.0433        0.3123
```

I'd like to have a `Volatility` of `0.035` and the maximized `Return` for that volatility.

That is, I'd like, in a new `Df` the `Name` and the percentage of that asset that will be in my `portfolio` that gives the maximum `Return` for a `Volatility` equals to `0.035`.

Therefore, I need to solve a system of equations with multiple conditions, to obtain the best solution (Highest`Return`) for a fixed outcome (`Volatility == 0.035`).

The conditions are:

- Each asset has a weight between 0 and 1.
- The sum of the weights is 1.
- The sum of the weights times the volatility of each asset is the "Desired Volatility".
- The sum of the weights times the return of each asset is the "Total Return". This should be maximized.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492434/rounding-datetime-based-on-time-of-day/59493101
Shows how to write custom  functions and apply it to a dataframe

Comment: Can you show what should be the result in this example?

Comment: "I want to solve a system of equations with multiple conditions" – which equations? which conditions? how are they related to the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using [Z3Py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm), an open source [SAT/SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) solver.
In a SAT/SMT solver you can write your code just as a list of conditions, and the program finds an optimal solution (or just a solution that satisfies all the conditions when Z3 is used as solver).

Originally SAT solvers only worked with pure boolean expressions, but modern SAT/SMT solvers also allow for fixed-bit and unlimited integers, fractions, reals and even functions as central variable.

To write the given equations into Z3, they are converted quite literally into Z3 expressions. The code below comments each of the steps.

```py
import pandas as pd
from z3 import *

DesiredVolatility = 0.035
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Volatility', 'Return'],
                  data=[['a', 0.0243, 0.212],
                        ['b', 0.0321, 0.431],
                        ['c', 0.0323, 0.443],
                        ['d', 0.0391, 0.2123],
                        ['e', 0.0433, 0.3123]])

# create a Z3 instance to optimize something
s = Optimize()
# the weight of each asset, as a Z3 variable
W = [Real(row.Name) for row in df.itertuples()]
# the total volatility
TotVol = Real('TotVol')
# the total return, to be maximized
TotReturn = Real('TotReturn')

# weights between 0 and 1, and sum to 1
s.add(And([And(w >= 0, w <= 1) for w in W]))
s.add(Sum([w for w in W]) == 1)
# the total return is calculated as the weighted sum of the asset returns
s.add(TotReturn == Sum([w * row.Return for w, row in zip(W, df.itertuples())]))
# the volatility is calculated as the weighted sum of the asset volatility
s.add(TotVol == Sum([w * row.Volatility for w, row in zip(W, df.itertuples())]))
# the volatility should be equal to the desired volatility
s.add(TotVol == DesiredVolatility)
# we're maximizing the total return
h1 = s.maximize(TotReturn)
# we ask Z3 to do its magick
res = s.check()
# we check the result, hoping for 'sat': all conditions satisfied, a maximum is found
if res == sat:
    s.upper(h1)
    m = s.model()
    #for w in W:
    #    print(f'asset {w}): {m[w]} = {m[w].numerator_as_long() / m[w] .denominator_as_long() : .6f}')
    # output the total return
    print(f'Total Return: {m[TotReturn]} = {m[TotReturn].numerator_as_long() / m[TotReturn] .denominator_as_long() :.6f}')
    # get the proportions out of the Z3 model
    proportions = [m[w].numerator_as_long() / m[w] .denominator_as_long() for w in W]
    # create a dataframe with the result
    df_result = pd.DataFrame({'Name': df.Name, 'Proportion': proportions})
    print(df_result)
else:
    print("No satisfiable solution found")
```

Result:

```
Total Return: 452011/1100000 = 0.410919
  Name  Proportion
0    a    0.000000
1    b    0.000000
2    c    0.754545
3    d    0.000000
4    e    0.245455
```

You can easily add additional constraints, for example "no asset can have more than 30% of the total":

```
# change 
s.add(And([And(w >= 0, w <= 1) for w in W]))`
# to
s.add(And([And(w >= 0, w <= 0.3) for w in W]))`
```

Which would result in:

```
Total Return: 558101/1480000 = 0.377095
  Name  Proportion
0    a    0.082432
1    b    0.300000
2    c    0.300000
3    d    0.017568
4    e    0.300000
```

Comment: Is there a way to put the restriction : No item can have more than 30% of the total allocation ?

Comment: Sure, just change `s.add(And([And(w >= 0, w <= 1) for w in W]))` to `s.add(And([And(w >= 0, w <=  0.3) for w in W]))`. In that case we get a return of 0.377 and proportions `[0.082, 0.3, 0.3, 0.018, 0.3]`