# How to do Portfolio Optimization with constraints on the number of assets?

Tags: python, solver, z3py

I am trying to minimize the volatility on a certain return subject to four constraints.

1. Every asset has a weight between 0 and 1
2. The sum of all weights is equal to 1
3. The return of the portfolio composed with the assets is equal to the given return
4. Only a maximum of 3 out of the 5 assets are used

I have tried doing it with Scipy minimize this way :

```
cons_3 = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -np.count_nonzero(x) + 3}, 
          {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: statistics(x)[0] - tret_3}, 
          {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
x0 = [1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 0]
res_3 = sco.minimize(min_func_port, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds_3, constraints=cons_3)
```

But apparently it is not possible.

I also read that it was possible using Z3Py but I can't seem to find the right way to code it. Here is what I found so far :

```
import pandas as pd
from z3 import *

DesiredReturn = 0.05
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Return', 'Volatility'],
                  data=[['Asset_1', 0.01744, 0.694149],
                        ['Asset_2', 0.03818, 0.475544],
                        ['Asset_3', 0.08218, 0.500724],
                        ['Asset_4', 0.09818, 0.489052],
                        ['Asset_5', 0.04272, 0.706223]])

W = [Real(row.Name) for row in df.itertuples()]
Vol = Real('Vol')
Ret = Real('Ret')
s = Optimize()
s.add(And([And(w >= 0, w <= 1) for w in W]))
s.add(Sum([w for w in W]) == 1)
#Missing constraint
s.add(Ret == Sum([w * row.Return for w, row in zip(W, df.itertuples())]))
s.add(Vol == Sum([w * row.Volatility for w, row in zip(W, df.itertuples())]))
s.add(Ret == DesiredReturn)
h1 = s.minimize(Vol)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Let's assume that the correlations between the Assets are equal to zero for the example.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: See also [How to solve a system of equations and constraints for portfolio optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790285/how-to-solve-a-system-of-equations-and-constraints-for-portfolio-optimization/59790650#59790650)

Comment: @JohanC I actually got my example template from your comment on that post. Thank you very much you helped me understand how optimization with Z3Py works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close in your encoding. Below is how I'd code it. (I'm avoiding pandas since I don't have it installed..)

```py
from z3 import *

Data = [  ['Asset_1', 0.01744, 0.694149]
       ,  ['Asset_2', 0.03818, 0.475544]
       ,  ['Asset_3', 0.08218, 0.500724]
       ,  ['Asset_4', 0.09818, 0.489052]
       ,  ['Asset_5', 0.04272, 0.706223]
       ]

# Weights
W = [Real(row[0]) for row in Data]

# Return and Volatility
Ret = Sum([w * row[1] for (w, row) in zip(W, Data)])
Vol = Sum([w * row[2] for (w, row) in zip(W, Data)])

o = Optimize()

# 1. Every weight is between 0 and 1
o.add([And(w >= 0, w <= 1) for w in W])

# 2. They sum up to 1
o.add(Sum([w for w in W]) == 1)

# 3. Return is what was requested
DesiredReturn = 0.05
o.add(Ret == DesiredReturn)

# 4. Only a maximum of 3 out of the 5 assets are used
o.add(Sum([If(w == 0, 0, 1) for w in W]) <= 3)

# Want to minimize volatility
o.minimize(Vol)

r = o.check()
if r == sat:
    m = o.model()
    prec = 10
    for w in W:
         print("%s    = %s" % (w, m[w].as_decimal(prec)))
    print("Return     = %s" % m.evaluate(Ret).as_decimal(prec))
    print("Volatility = %s" % m.evaluate(Vol).as_decimal(prec))
else:
    print("solver said: %s" % r)
```

When run, this prints:

```
Asset_1    = 0
Asset_2    = 0.803
Asset_3    = 0
Asset_4    = 0.197
Asset_5    = 0
Return     = 0.05
Volatility = 0.478205076
```

Comment: I suppose here we are assuming 0 correlation between assets. How do we incorporate non-zero volatility?